# Apple Approval for saving all the User-Data (including images) to iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I want to develop an iOS app which consists of array of items and each item will have some text data along with the Image. I don't want to use the external server and want to make use of iCloud to store all the user data. User will be provided with any option to enable/disable the iCloud sync. Each item's data (text and image) will be wrapped inside the directory and gonna synced to iCloud, for this I'll be using UIDocument approach.

I went through the internet and found that unless we are storing NON-USER GENERATED DATA in iCloud, we won't be facing any problem in Apple Review Process. Please let me know whether my understanding is right here and is there any possibility of rejection from Apple. Just want to be double sure before proceeding towards the implementation.

Also, are there any other important points I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know whether my understanding is right here and is there any possibility of rejection from Apple.

The first thing to understand is that there is **always** the possibility of Apple rejecting your app, for any reason. Their terms basically say that they can reject anything they want for any reason, even if you're not doing anything that violates anything on their list of rules. There is no guarantee that Apple won't reject your app, ever, full stop.

**As you describe your app** there is nothing obviously breaking any of Apple's rules, so it sounds like you're OK. That assumes that the images are not something that could be re-downloaded at some point, e.g. that they're photos or some other kind of image created on the device and not downloaded from somewhere. No guarantees, but odds of Apple rejecting you specifically for this reason are low.